# how to create mailbox in exchange server 2010

Tags: exchange

I installed exchange server 2010 for the first time after the using of exchange server 2003 and now want to create mailbox for the existing users.
 But I did,nt get any good article from any where.
 I am confiused to create the mailbox in "Server configuration" or in "recipent configuration,so please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the GUI under Recipient Configuration > New Mailbox > User Mailbox > Existing User, and choose the user you wish to create the mailbox for.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998319.aspx

From the shell: `Enable-Mailbox john@contoso.com -Database "MyServer\Mailbox Database"`

You must be logged in with an account with sufficient privilege to create a mailbox in Exchange.

As an aside, there have been reported issues with the built-in Domain Administrator account and Exchange 2010. If you experience any issues with the built-in account, create a new account with administrative privilege.

Comment: Thanks Mike,dear as I use the exchange server 2010 for the first time and only want to configure mailbox so as there are any more setting or it is enough.

Comment: Since this is the first mailbox, I assume you are going to store the data in the default database. In the GUI you can set an alias as well. For a simple exchange configuration, setting up the initial users in the default database should be sufficient. You can always migrate them to another database at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mailbox in Exchange using Powershell command or using  Exchange Management Console (EMC). But, Process is little bit long using EMC. Go though this Microsoft help section > technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998319(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the link becomes invalid.